# Facebook App Permission issue when deleting some Comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments, http-delete

I am having issues deleting a comment on my page via Facebook Graph API. My app has subscribed to all necessary permissions and the page token I have has all the necessary permissions for post moderation, including `pages_manage_engagement` and `pages_read_engagement` permissions indicated here `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/comment/#deleting`.

Ironically, I am able to delete some comments made by admins on my page but for others, I get the following exception:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#200) App does not have sufficient permission for this action",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 200,
        "fbtrace_id": "AEb1bLEPhjgypCFBLr2FjiI"
    }
}
```

When trying to get the comment from Facebook to check if It can be deleted, I get

```
{
    "id": "xxxxxx",
    "from": {
        "name": "xxxx",
        "id": "xxxxx"
    },
    "message": "some message to delete",
    "is_hidden": false,
    **"can_remove": true,**
    "can_hide": false
}
```

Please what am I doing wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.

I am using the following endpoint
`https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/comment_id`
with an Http delete request.
PS: v7.0 has the same result.

Comment: Is your app in live or in dev mode? In the latter, this is probably not expected to work, I guess.

Comment: the app is live. As I mentioned, deletion works in some cases and not in others, which is very confusing